# How make this sql. ( conditions sql )

Tags: sql, mysql

Query:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM Post 
ORDER BY Post.rating <-- Here , i want ( Post.rating * 5 ) when Post.recommended = 1 )
```

**Thanks all people.**

Comment: i dont understand your question. can you please elaborate or make the question clearer. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT p.*
    FROM POST p
ORDER BY CASE 
           WHEN p.recommended = 1 THEN p.rating * 5
           ELSE p.rating
         END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Post 
ORDER BY case Post.rating when 1 then post.rating * 5 else post.rating end
```

Comment: Three essentially identical answers within 1 minute.  With luck, at least one of us is right!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
SELECT *
  FROM Post
 ORDER BY CASE Recommended WHEN 1 THEN Rating * 5 ELSE Rating END
```

Since there's only one table, the column references are unambiguous, so I removed the `Post.` prefixes, which avoids the horizontal scroll-bar.

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM Post 
ORDER BY Post.rating * IF(recommended = 1, 5, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Post 
ORDER BY if(Post.recommended = 1,Post.rating * 5,Post.rating)
```