# RE: How make this sql. ( conditions sql )

Tags: sql, mysql

I questioned here this: 
[How make this sql. ( conditions sql )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827690/how-make-this-sql-conditions-sql)

but now, I want

```
SELECT SUM( Post.rating ) as countRating <--- THIS i want Post.rating * 5 WHEN Post.recommended = 1
FROM posts as Post
ORDER BY countRating DESC
```

help me

Comment: One of the intentions of SO is to help you learn how to think.  You need to meditate on previous answers given you, and see how they can be applied to new situations.

Comment: because i dont ever use this. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, use the same technique as in the answers to the other question - use a CASE expression, this time in the SUM instead of in the ORDER BY clause.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE Recommended WHEN 1 THEN 5 ELSE 1 END * Rating) AS countRating
  FROM posts as Post
 ORDER BY countRating DESC
```

If the alternative value for Recommended is 0 (a plausible guess), then you could also write:

```
SELECT SUM((4 * Recommended + 1) * Rating) AS countRating
  FROM posts as Post
 ORDER BY countRating DESC
```

And, indeed, you could do the same with the ORDER BY clause in the previous question.

Comment: Thanks a alot ^^, I couldn't accept your question because system dont allow, It alert "You can accept an answer in 6 minutes". I 'll accept when i return here